# Tags Info; Link to SO tags or project pages?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki, hyperlinks, external-links

In some tag info tabs we have links to related technologies.
Sometimes authors link to the SO page of that technology (if exists), sometimes to the technology project page.

First, Which one is better/recommended?

Second, if the SO links are recommended, should we link to SO tag info page or questions page?

Example:
In [Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shopify/info) tag info the link is to Liquid tag questions, but in [Liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liquid) tag info the link is to shopify.com